# Quick search items in collection

Tags: javascript, arrays, search

I have a script which manipulates objects of `Item`. Every item has unique set of properties (`a`, `b` and `c`), lets call them coordinates.

I created object of `Collection` which contains `items` array. Now I can quickly find them by index.

And also I want to find them by coordinates. I implemented the method `findByAbc` which uses hashes. If all three coordinates are specified it works good.

But now I want to implement a search by one or two coordinates, so it should return array of items. I created `findCustom` method which iterates all items and compares their coordinates. But this implementation is slow.

**Is it possible to make a quick search?**

See the example: http://jsfiddle.net/29zguzs5/

I thought about to implement the search by two coordinates like this:

```
findByAb: (a, b)->
  aItems = @findByA(a)
  bItems = @findByB(b)
  items = findCommonItems(aItems, bItems)
```

But I think that comparing two arrays is also slow.

So, do you have any ideas how to implement it?

**UPD.**

I think about the Collection as a multi-dimensional (3d) array (or hash). If you specify only two indexes, it should return a line of items. Maybe there are some existing implementations?

Comment: What do you mean by "Now I can quickly find them by index."? Do you need to access items by this index, or does it always suffice to access by coordinates?

Comment: a) Search by index - works good.

b) Search by three coordinates - good.

c) Search by one or two coordinates - slow. This is the actual question.

Comment: What I meant is: why don't you just use a 3 dimensional array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the fasetes way to do it with JavaScript: create indexes for each of combination of properties, like below:

```
// Somewhere in constructor
this.indexA = {};
this.indexB = {};
this.indexAB = {};
an so on...
```

Then fill indexes with values. You can do it in the loop or at the time of insert() operation:

```
Collection.prototype.reindex = function(){
    for(var i=0;i<this.items.length;i++) {
        this.indexA[this.items[i].a] = this.items;
        this.indexB[this.items[i].b] = this.items;
        this.indexAB[this.items[i].a+'~'+this.items[i].b] = this.items;
    }
};

Collection.prototype.insert = function(val) {
    this.items.push(val);
    this.indexA[val.a] = val;
    this.indxB[val.a] = val;
    this.indexAB[val.a+'~'+val.b] = val;
}

Collection.prototype.getAB = function(a,b) {
    return this.indexAB[a+'~'+b];
}
```

This is only draft of functions and they are not universal (more ideas than ready solutions), but we used this approach in our JavaScript SQL database library because it is fast.

To create index values you can use something like:

```
function createKey(coordArray) {
    return coordArray.join('~');
}
```

Here '~' is just unusual character, it can be replaced with any other UNICODE char, like String.fromCharCode(0)

PS. sorry, for JS, not CoffeeScript.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good idea, will try it. Btw, I'm interested about your JS SQL lib. Is it possible to see it in action?